# DISQUS API - find thread by URL

Tags: php, api, disqus

I am working with the DISQUS API and I want to search for a thread via the URL.

I am using the official client library: https://github.com/disqus/disqus-php

So basically I have created a function that calls the API in this manner:

```
     private function getThread($URL){

        $params = array(
            'forum' => $this->shortname,
            'thread' => ("link:" . $URL)
        );

        $thread = $this->API->threads->list($params);

        Debug::dump($thread);
        exit;
    }
```

However it seems that the URL filtering is not working since the returned result is all the threads in my forum.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm successfully pulling the needed information like this:

```
require('disqusapi/disqusapi.php');

$disqus = new DisqusAPI('API_SECRET_KEY');

$thread = $disqus->forums->listThreads(array(
    'forum' => 'FORUM_SHORT_NAME',
    'thread' => 'link:URL_OF_THE_THREAD'
));
```

All in all, the ***link:*** element should be part of the actual parameter value rather than it's key as others suggested.

Answer (score 1):

"link" is not a valid parameter options.  To filter threads by URL, the parameter you need to pass is "thread:link".

To get the thread by URL:
https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/list.json?api_key=[api_key]&forum=[forum]&thread:link=[url]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems that the url it doesn't work. Instead of this it's displaying the last 25 threads. I have tried to use another disqus URL by disqus documentation. I have tried this one **https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/listPosts.json** which returns a list of posts within a thread. Though it didn't work again. What I found though it's that both work if you have the ID of the thread instead of the URL. To do this I had to catch up the ID from my website. Then to put the ID in a parameter and pass it at the URL. It seems kind of tricky but for me it worked. Also the limit for the threads to be displayed is 100 maximum so no matter what if your thread it's too old it will not find it. I tried to put more parameters like category, author etc but still didn't work. So in my opinion catch up the ID from the thread through your website ( I did with xmlDoc and took the disqus code by getElemenetsByTag, which contains the ID of the thread). I don't know if I helped, but as you can see I have the same problem too. Unfortunatelly Disqus Api doesn't give you the opportunity to put more parameters which could help. Anyway, still it's good. For now I will be doing it like this.